# Javascript file not including inside html page

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to use JQuery inside a ASP.NET MVC practice project but the site.js file not working or including inside html page. If I write JQuery code inside script tag in html then it's working fine, Even I have included some other files like Bootstrap and site.css that also working only problem with site.js file.

## Site.js

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    alert("Hello 1");
});

$(window).load(function () {
    alert("Hello 2");
});
```

## _Layout.cshtml

Including snippet

```
<script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="~/js/site.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="~/lib/jquery-validation/dist/jquery.validate.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: You are including "site.min.js" instead of "site.js". Could that be the issue?

Comment: I tried both of them, that was my last try snippet.

Comment: No need to try both unless you have both version on your server. Open the DevTools and on either Source or Network tab, check if you successfully loaded the js file.

Comment: try replace dollar sign with jQuery(document)...

Answer (score 0):

your source is starting from lib and js folder. if  your js folder is in your content folder than please use content after tilt sign

```
<script src="~/Content/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since we don't want to guess and have no view of your specific project do this:

1. Open your project.
2. Find the missing js file in the project
3. Open your layout file
4. In Visual Studio, drag the js file and drop it on the layout file
5. Revise your layout to use the js file location as in the dropped link

Test

Note normally it is a "Scripts" folder by default

Answer (score 0):

Drag and drop the site.js file from the solution explorer into the view, it should add the correct path. If that doesn't work try to put this:

```
(function($) {
    $(document).ready(function () {
        alert("Hello 1");
    });

    $(window).load(function () {
        alert("Hello 2");
    });
})(jQuery);
```

I'm not sure how does the (function($){//code})(jQuery); works, but in the past solved my problem.